# Java code for closing a file that is open in java(TM) platform SE binary

Tags: r.java-file

I have java code in my application for deleting a file i.e nameOffile.delete(). As I try to delete the file I get an error: The action can not be completed because the file is open in Java (TM) Platform SE binary. Close the file and try again. I tried deleting the file without the application but I still get the same problem. Please help me solve thes error.

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

You were probably opening the file first to read/write its content?
There you probably forgot to close the stream. Therefore you are not able to delete it.

```
Writer out = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName), fEncoding);
try {
  out.write("some text here");
}
finally {
  out.close();
}

// write code to delete the file
```

Answer (score 0):

To solve this problem open task manager and close java then you'll be able to delete the file